# Nexus theme tb mega menu showing below slideshow

Tags: 7, navigation

I am using the [Nexus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nexus) theme however when using [tb mega menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) it shows below the slideshow. I know it has something to do with the z-index but where and how do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the class of tb mega menu and add

```
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Note: z-index max display on top.**

Comment: Where is the class

Comment: You need to inspect on browser and check.Actually I have not set up for that particular situation.